# Is punctuation necessary for displayed formulas in academia writing?

Tags: writing

If a formula appears in the main body of the text, there seems no doubt that punctuation should be given to that formula when necessary. But when a formula appears *displayed* (i.e. solely taking up a line), there seems no consensus on whether punctuation is needed for it. I wonder if there will be any potential ambiguities if punctuation is (or not) included in this case.

This is essentially a question about *functions* of punctuation for displayed formulas. I don't want an answer about *rules* from certain style guide...

Comment: The exact same question was asked before on MathOverflow. You can read the question, comments, and nice answers here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6675/periods-and-commas-in-mathematical-writing

Comment: You can take a look at the American Mathematical Society book [Mathematics into type](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf) (pdf) for some guidance on typesetting mathematics.

Answer (score 16):

In mathematics there is a near universal consensus that displayed mathematics should not be treated differently from inline mathematics with regards to punctuation. By this I mean that the vast majority of papers on the arXiv follow this convention, most journals will add punctuation according to this principle if it's not already there, and so on.

Thus whenever you're unsure whether or not to include punctuation at the end of a displayed equation, try to replace `\[ ... \]` with `$ ... $` - whatever punctuation mark looks natural when it's inlined should be included also at the end of the displayed equation.

I don't think that texts without punctuation after displayed equations are necessarily *ambiguous*, but then again, a text without punctuation after inlined equations would probably not be ambiguous either. The main purpose of punctuation is after all not to reduce ambiguity but to increase readability and "flow" of the text.

Comment: ... maybe not-quite-universal... but, yes, the very fact that anyone at all would believe that there was such a consensus is the data point. I don't mean to disparage anyone by expressing doubt that there's "near consensus", and, indeed, there may be, but I do wish to register at least a small dissent, as in my "answer"...

Comment: Well, I was careful to write "*near* universal consensus", and so on. ;) Anyway, I think a random sampling of papers on the arXiv will confirm how widely this convention is accepted, although I don't have the urge to carry out a scientific study...

Comment: @paulgarrett "But I have come to the conclusion that that eliminating visual junk from the printed page is more important than punctuatory pedantry, so that when the same formulas is _displayed_, for example $$t^2+1$$ then it looks silly if the comma is included, like this, $$t^2+1,$$ and everything is much cleaner and less ambiguous without punctuation."--Preface of _Galois_ _Theory_ (third edition) by Ian Stewart.

Comment: @paulgarrett In effect I also wonder when this "convention" formed. 150 years ago, there seemed no such convention. For instance, see Riemann's 1859 manuscript: http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Riemann_Hypothesis/1859_manuscript/riemann1859-1a.jpg Some of the displayed formulas have punctuation attached, but some don't. Maybe only most _English_ papers today follow this "convention"?

Comment: @ZhouFang Do you have a transcript of the text? Very likely the formulas that don't have it there shouldn't have it, because you don't but a comma at that place in a sentence. It's not like that every formula gets punctuation, it's that every formula which should have one gets one.

Comment: @tohecz Yes! See http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Riemann_Hypothesis/1859_manuscript/EZeta.pdf Notably, the translator does not change the way how Riemann used punctuation for displayed formulas. (The last formula on the first page certainly _can_ have a comma attached.)

Comment: @tohecz Also see the German version: http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Riemann_Hypothesis/1859_manuscript/zeta.pdf

Comment: @ZhouFang Nice! Then notice that whenever there's _no punctuation_ after a displayed formula, there _should not be_ any, or at least _need not be_. It seems to me that either German has a different sense of commas than English and the translator kept this sense, or the translator was quite loose on commas. However, you can easily check that he keeps all the full stops as they should be. +1 to both comments for finding it! :)

Comment: @tohecz Regarding your last sentence: not necessarily. See the last displayed formula in the paper for instance.

Comment: @ZhouFang Very boundary case (I discussed it elsewhere here I think) with "mathematical ellipsis" `...` at the end of a sentence. I would have an additional dot there, someone else would not, and a third person would ask the author to re-write it to avoid this problem ;) However, to me it looks like the only exceptional point.

Comment: @tohecz I was actually joking... but I'm pretty amazed that you would really write an additional dot there... :)

Answer (score 6):

As a probably-minority opinion, I try to avoid having English-language punctuation juxtaposed to mathematical notation, especially anything complicated, whenever possible. Also, I try to avoid beginning a sentence with mathematical notation, trying, instead, to begin with an obvious English word that is capitalized.

In that vein, I do not put periods or commas at the right edge of displayed purely-formulaic expressions, but have the next line start with a capitalized English word, signifying new-sentence.

My objection to juxtaposition of English-punctuation with formulas is the visual noise, small though it may be. At least my own perception of my own scanning of English+mathematics is that I think of English in a somewhat different manner than I think of the mathematics (apart from small naming-phrases), and everything's easier if the two functions of "comma" and "period" are clearly distinguished.

Comment: Maybe the customs are field-dependent, and not so universal outside maths: I have checked my own papers (in both physics and chemistry journals), and it's a mixed bag of punctation and no-punctuation… So **not all publishers favor punctuation in displayed formulas!**

Comment: I try to punctuate displayed formulas, but I'll take out the punctuation is it's really distracting.  But I'm religious about not starting sentences with mathematical notation, so I have lots of sentences that start "The set S..." or "The graph G...".  More generally I try to separate any two "phrases" of mathematical notation with at least one English word.  (Commas do _not_ mean "and" or "where" or (shudder) "for all"!)

Comment: I am amused that there was a down-vote, mostly because I am acquainted with people who have _VERY_ strong feelings about this... apart from house-styles at journals, which have brow-beaten me into adding marks. Naturally, "clarity" is context-dependent, ... but I am entirely unconvinced that "rules" truly enforce "clarity", etc. But, perhaps, the lesson is that the people who believe that displays must be punctuated as though they were English have powerful beliefs, while those who doubt ... are not as aggressive... not burning the crops and villages. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett I'm strongly tempted to downvote this too, because I see this opinion as quite wrong. Yes, there are publishers who consider punctuation in math wrong, but as well, there are publishers who publish journals double-spaces, so I don't think that this is a good measure.

Comment: @JeffE Two of the basic rules for mixing math and text say: 1) never math at a beginning of a sentence, 2) each two in-line formulas should be seperated by a word. _Bad example:_ **Theorem:** $H(v)=H(u)$. If $G(v)=G(u)$, $K=0$. _Better example:_ **Theorem:** We have $H(v)=H(u)$. If moreover $G(v)=G(u)$, then $K=0$.

Comment: @tohecz, I did not mean to use any publishers' house styles as evidence for-or-against natural-language punctuation in displayed math. My argument, such as it is, is entirely in terms of scan-ability and separation of mathematical function of small marks (which is very sensitive) from natural-language function of small marks, which is both different and more robust in an information-theory sense.

Comment: However, A punctuation mark at the end of a display formula cannot be mis-interpreted as a math thingy, not even in cases like `\[ i^2 \quad \text{for } i=1,2,3,\dotsc .\]` (which should be avoided at all, for obvious reasons, but that's another story and quite a special case). I basically wanted to put some light on why someone else might have downvoted you. The "scan-ability", as you describe you, is probably quite subjective. That's why typographic rules have been established: To give things a unique look even when the feelings or each of us differ quite significantly ;)

Comment: @tohecz, ah, "rules"? :) I am quite far from being a prescriptivist, although there seems to be a general tendency among mathematicians to prescriptivism (say, in contrast to descriptivism).

Comment: They are rules. They may be loose or tight, they may change in time, they may be followed or be not. But they are rules. And we are too chatty, let's end this. We can discuss a bit in the chat if you wish, but I have to go soon.

Comment: Dear @tohecz, please read the last paragraph of my question.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: Yes, of course. No matter what is the formatting on the page, the text is *linear*, with the only exceptions being floating objects (figures and tables), which obviously *float*. The fact whether the formula is on display or not should have no implication on the punctuation used.

This issue exactly is not much addressed by Knuth in his [Mathematical writing](http://jmlr.org/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf). Still, him being a profesionnal typographer, a mathematician and an author of many books, his opinion on this (which is clear if you open any of his works) is IMHO quite valuable, being a strong reference for proper punctuation. The linked article is definitely worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for including the punctuation is that text with math in it is still text. The reason for leaving it out is that it looks ugly because we're juxtaposing elements of two writing systems in which symbols have completely different meanings. Either possibility can be jarring to the reader.

A good way to deal with these problems is to leave some white space between the equation and the punctuation.

```
The Pythagorean theorem,
  A^2+B^2=C^2    ,
has been known since ancient times.
```

In LaTeX, I use a \qquad for this.

In my personal style, I also sometimes end a sentence with a displayed equation set off by a colon, without a period after the equation.

```
Thus from Euclid's five postulates we arrive at our final result,
known as the Pythagorean theorem:
  A^2+B^2=C^2
```

Here I feel that the colon acts like a signal on the tracks that tells the train conductor we're nearing the end of the sentence. The construction of the sentence also reinforces the reader's subconscious expectation that the sentence will not continue after the equation. Grammatically, the equation does not function as any part of speech; the style is similar to what one would use in introducing a diagram that was in-line in the body of the text and had no caption or figure number.

Comment: Ick.  I find the \qquad considerably _more_ distracting than just putting the comma against the formula.

Comment: I can see the good intent, but the non-standardness itself (as innocent as it is) may be more distracting than the original-bad-thing. Dunno.

Comment: Downvote. Never . Ever . Put . A . Space . Before . Punctuation . (Unless you are French.)